# XSS vulnerability in javascript

Tags: javascript, xss, fortify

Fortify showing XSS vulnerability for following code on document.write

```
for (var i in this.links)
{
 if (i == this.links.length - 1)
 {
   document.write(((i == 0) ? "" : " | ") + this.text[i]);
 }
 else
 {
   document.write(((i == 0) ? "" : " | ") + "<a href='" + this.links[i] + "'>" + this.text[i] + "</a>");
 }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: so do not use document.write

Comment: how can I resolve this issue

Comment: Hello @Amit, welcome to StackOverflow, we recommend and encourage you to read the Faqs and also take a look at How to Ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You need to sanitize your data before you use document.write. Also, since you're inserting HTML into the DOM you are opening yourself up for DOM XSS Attacks.

I advise you to read [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes) on how to prevent XSS and [this](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Attribute_Subcontext_within_the_Execution_Context) to prevent DOM based XSS attacks